# Can you guide me with a question, I am trying to change the color every time I press a button

Tags: javascript, php, html

My problem is that I call my function within my for, but only a part changes color and not above each record, the buttons work but the color of the corresponding row does not change, it had occurred to me to send a value that could be the pk of my table and this one that is changing in the for, if you know any way to achieve that I would really appreciate it

```
<!doctype html>


<html lang="es">
<head>

<body>


          <?php 
               
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !hash_equals($_SESSION['csrf'], $_POST['csrf'])) {
  die();
}

$error = false;
$config = include 'ClientesBeta/conexion/config.php';

try {
  $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db']['name'];
  $conexion = new PDO($dsn, $config['db']['user'], $config['db']['pass'], $config['db']['options']);

  if (isset($_POST['marca'])) {
    $consultaSQL = "SELECT * FROM zonas WHERE idZonas <> 1 and nombreZona LIKE '%" . $_POST['marca'] . "%'";
  } else {
    $consultaSQL = "SELECT * FROM zonas where idZonas <> 1";
  }

  $sentencia = $conexion->prepare($consultaSQL);
  $sentencia->execute();

  $alumnos = $sentencia->fetchAll();

} catch(PDOException $error) {
  $error= $error->getMessage();
}
            ?>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="margin-top:20px;">
                <thead>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Zona</th>
                    
                    <th>Acción</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
          if ($alumnos && $sentencia) {
              
            foreach ($alumnos as $row) {
                
              ?>
              
  <tr>
   
    <td  id="prueba2"></td>   
    <td id="prueba"></td>
     <td id="prueba1"></td>
      <td >
<button  type="button" onclick="cambiarColor2();">Inicio</button>
<button type="button" onclick="cambiarColor();">Proceso</button>
<button type="button" onclick="cambiarColor1();">Fin</button>
</td>

<script>
          function cambiarColor(){
    document.getElementById('prueba').style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  }
    </script>
    <script>
          function cambiarColor1(){
    document.getElementById('prueba1').style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
    </script>
    <script>
          function cambiarColor2(){
    document.getElementById('prueba2').style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
    </script>
  </tr>

              <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['idZonas']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['nombreZona']; ?></td>
                                    
                                    
                                </tr>
                                <?php 
                            }
                        }
                        

                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not in english

Comment: Please post this on [es.so]

Comment: It is hard for anyone to run your code bcs we don't have your database and records.  In reality, the problem seems to be just about the HTML and JS that are generated, right?  So we don't need the database or PHP code, all we need is your generated HTML.  Try to create a **simplified** [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - just some of your HTML, and the JS. Then it is easy for everyone to run it and try to help.  Take some care with formatting to make it even easier.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand your question. But I believe you are looking for the below answer. Let me know if it helps you.

I think you have placed the ID in the wrong tags, though. Changed the id to where you want to change the colour. I haven't tested the code also.

```
<?php 
if ($alumnos && $sentencia) {
    foreach ($alumnos as $key => $row) {?>
        <tr>
            <td id="prueba2_<?php echo $key; ?>"></td>   
            <td id="prueba0_<?php echo $key; ?>"></td>
            <td id="prueba1_<?php echo $key; ?>"></td>
            <td>
                <button  type="button" onclick="cambiarColor(<?php echo $key; ?>, 2, 'green');">Inicio</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="cambiarColor(<?php echo $key; ?>, 0, 'blue');">Proceso</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="cambiarColor(<?php echo $key; ?>, 1, 'red');">Fin</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['idZonas']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['nombreZona']; ?></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
<?php 
    }
}
?>
<script>
    function cambiarColor(id, eleid color){
        document.getElementById('prueba'+eleid+'_'+id).style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
</script>
```